# Can I get a new cracker?

Tags: hacker-experience

My cracker has been deleted or hidden. I don't have the software to unhide it. Is it possible to download a new cracker without restarting the whole game?

Answer (score 1):

The Download center allows you to download a 1.0 Cracker to get you back on your feet.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to get it back unless you download one from the Download Center (https://legacy.hackerexperience.com/internet?ip=241.151.9.102) or you can go through the riddles/puzzles to get back up to that level; Or if you still have the money just research on the level one cracker (it's not the best way but it's another way for the rich and people who have a lot of time.)

Comment: You need a cracker to do the puzzles.

Comment: I'm late to reply to this, but you are correct. You need a cracker to do the puzzles. The Download Center provides one.